# How can I remove the first page of a PDF file with Java?

Tags: java, pdf

I was thinking about using a library such as [PDFBox](http://incubator.apache.org/pdfbox/) but I would like your input.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/), it works pretty well for manipulating PDFs or even constructing them from scratch.

There is also a [tutorial](http://itextdocs.lowagie.com/tutorial/general/copystamp/index.php) on how to manipulate PDFs. I didn't see a way to delete pages, but the tool supports creating a new PDF by copying content from another one. So you could just copy all the pages but the first.

Answer (score 1):

With [IText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/)

```
public void removeFirstPage(String input_filename, String output_filename) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    File outFile = new File(output_filename);
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input_filename);
    int pages_number = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    if(pages_number > 0) {
        Document document = new Document(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(outFile));
        document.open();
    for(int i=2; i <= pages_number;i++) {
            PdfImportedPage page = copy.getImportedPage(reader, i);
        copy.addPage(page);
    }
        document.close();        
    }
}
```